# Swift Realm retrieving data

Tags: swift, realm

I'm having a problem with retrieving data from a Realm Database that I have created.  I have created an object titled ProgramAnswerRealm as below:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

public class ProgramAnswerRealm: Object {
    var answerChosen: String = ""
    var imagePath: String = ""
    dynamic var category: Category!


}
```

I am writing to this and when I declare the results to a variable I can see values within the immediate window.

```
po dataSource.last
▿ Optional<ProgramAnswerRealm>
  ▿ some : ProgramAnswerRealm {
    answerChosen = bird;
    imagePath = ;
    category = (null);
}
```

The problem is when I try to assign a variable to my answerChosen value using the following code:

```
dataSource.last!.answerChosen
```

I'm not able to get a value returned.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put **dynamic** when you declare your members.

When you mark a member declaration with the **dynamic modifier**, access to that member is always **dynamically dispatched** using the **Objective-C runtime**. Access to that member is **never inlined or devirtualized** by the compiler.

```
 public class ProgramAnswerRealm: Object {
    dynamic var answerChosen: String = ""
    dynamic var imagePath: String = ""
    dynamic var category: Category!
}
```

Don't forget if you want to add a **List** in your class **don't mark** the member declaration with the dynamic identifier.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models

Answer (score 1):

I figured the answer out.

It turns out I needed to declare the variables as dynamic for the Object.